# uncaught exception: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

The following block of code works:

```
$("#data\\[User\\]\\[notify_one_day_out\\]").val("0");
$('#data\\[User\\]\\[notify_one_day_out\\]').slider('disable');
$('#data\\[User\\]\\[notify_one_day_out\\]').slider('refresh');

$("#data\\[User\\]\\[notify_one_week_out\\]").val("0");
$('#data\\[User\\]\\[notify_one_week_out\\]').slider('disable');
$('#data\\[User\\]\\[notify_one_week_out\\]').slider('refresh');

$("#data\\[User\\]\\[notify_one_month_out\\]").val("0");
$('#data\\[User\\]\\[notify_one_month_out\\]').slider('disable');
$('#data\\[User\\]\\[notify_one_month_out\\]').slider('refresh');

$("#data\\[User\\]\\[notify_on_release_date_change\\]").val("0");
$('#data\\[User\\]\\[notify_on_release_date_change\\]').slider('disable');
$('#data\\[User\\]\\[notify_on_release_date_change\\]').slider('refresh');

$("#data\\[User\\]\\[notify_available_for_purchase\\]").val("0");
$('#data\\[User\\]\\[notify_available_for_purchase\\]').slider('disable');
$('#data\\[User\\]\\[notify_available_for_purchase\\]').slider('refresh');
```

when I try replacing the above with the following to condense the code:

```
      $('[id^="data"]').val('0');
            $('[id^="data"]').slider('disable');
            $('[id^="data"]').slider('refresh');
```

I get:

```
uncaught exception: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'
```

Comment: Does the second method select the same elements?

Comment: to the best of my knowledge yes. I mean it should only select all the form elements that start with "data"

Comment: Does the first method work if you rearrange the calls such that it uses the same order as the second method (i.e. first all `.val(0)` calls, etc)?

Answer (score 5):

Recently I had very similar problem and replacing

```
$('.sth').slider('disable');
```

with:

```
$('.sth').attr('disabled', true);
```

helped. Maybe this is worth try.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same error in a project I am working on and the fix was to initialize the sliders prior to using any methods, as the console error almost explicitly states.

See the jQuery Mobile Docs page on sliders. http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/slider/

Select all your sliders, call the slider() method to initialize, and the bug is zapped.

```
// Select all my inputs with the slider class, and initialize   
$('.slider').slider();
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you add `input` to your `[id^="data"]`. 
You might have divs or non-sliders with id=data-*something*.

Also try putting the code in the `pageinit` event for each page with sliders:

```
$('#page1,#page2,.sliderpage').on('pageinit', function() {
   $('input[id^=data]').val('0').slider('disabled', true).slider('refresh'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue was I had initialized the sliders in an earlier area of the code and the reference to `$(myfield).slider()` didn't then exist. Its also worth noting that this doesn't work when classes are used as the selector.

The solution I used was to define

`window['#'+$(this).attr('id')] = $('#'+$(this).attr('id')).slider();`

And then reference later on ...

`window['#'+id].slider('enable');` (or disable)

Hope that helps someone.